# SQL ServiceBroker Error "A previously existing connection with the same peer was found after DNS lookup" in sys.transmission_queue?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Service broker messages between our two servers have suddenly ceased working with multiple messages being written to `sys.transmission_queue` stating:

> A previously existing connection with the same peer was found after
>   DNS lookup. This connection will be closed. All traffic will be
>   redirected to the previously existing connection. This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required. State 116.

Both servers publish and receive messages to each other but nothing is flowing between the two.

- Server A is writing multiple entries to the `transmission_queue` but does not populate the transmission status with any value.
- Server B is also writing multiple entries but populates the status with the above message.

Traces have so far revealed nothing and this has only started occurring in the last few days.

The only solutions I can find suggested online are to restart the SQL instances but that seems drastic.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: I see that same message in my error logs all the time and I treat it as benign. Which doesn't help you solve your problem. Where I'd start though is an extended events session for one of the affected conversation handles. Which event? Hard to say. Search for "broker" in the extended events dialog. Make sure that you have all of the channels enabled!